# Fix position of Image without **position:fixed**

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I have a SideMenu bar. The Header of the sidemenu contains an image and below that are contents. It is scrollable. i want to make the menu scrollable and not the image. I cant use **position:fixed** because its a collapsable menu and some other reasons. How can i make only the contents scrollable?

CODE

```
document.write('<div> <img style="width:80%;margin:10%;"src="Files/Logo.png"/> <hr> </div>');

document.write('<div class="scroll">'+

document.write(
    '<button class="list" href="#X1" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle"> Home </button>'+
    '<div class="show list-unstyled" id="X1">'+
       '<a href="'+myArray[0][0]+'" class="'+myArray[0][1]+'" > Site 1 </a> '+
       '<a href="'+myArray[1][0]+'" class="'+myArray[1][1]+'" > Site 2 </a> '+
    '</div>'
);
document.write('</div>');
```

I tried putting seperat DIV but doesnt work

CSS

```
.scroll {
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: #000000;
}

#sidebar {
  min-width: 210px;
  max-width: 210px;
  background: #000000;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

FULL CODE

```
#sidebar {
  min-width: 210px;
  max-width: 210px;
  background: #000000;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}


#sidebar.active {
  min-width: 80px;
  max-width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}

#sidebar.active , button div a {
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin-left: 0;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-family: Verdana;
  background: #ffffff;
}

#sidebar.active .sidebar-header h3,
#sidebar.active .CTAs {
  display: none;
}

#sidebar.active .sidebar-header strong {
  display: block;
}
#sidebar.active .dropdown-toggle::after {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(50%);
  transform: translateX(50%);
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
  padding: 0;
  background: #000000;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header strong {
  display: none;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}
```

**COMPLETE CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

  <title>Collapsible sidebar using Bootstrap 4</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Our Custom CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Tags.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Nav.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Card.css"> -->
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Buttons.css"> -->
  <!-- Font Awesome JS -->
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper">

      <nav id="sidebar">
        <script src="C-NavigationBar.js"></script>
        <script src="JavaScript/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script>

           var y = document.getElementById(1);
           y.className += " w3-show";
           y.previousElementSibling.className += " w3-theme ";

              function myAccFunc(n) {
                var x = document.getElementById(n);
                if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
                  x.className += " w3-show";
                  x.previousElementSibling.className += " w3-theme ";
                } else {
                  x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
                  x.previousElementSibling.className =
                  x.previousElementSibling.className.replace("w3-theme", "");
                }
              }

              var editor = ace.edit("editor");
              editor.setTheme("ace/theme/twilight");
              editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/c_cpp");
              editor.setReadOnly(true);
              editor.resize();
        </script>
      </nav>


      <div id="content">

          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
              <div class="container-fluid">

                  <button style="width:auto;"type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-dark">
                      <i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i>
                      <span>Menu</span>
                  </button>



              </div>
          </nav>



      </div>
  </div>

  <!-- jQuery CDN - Slim version (=without AJAX) -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Popper.JS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
              $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
          });
      });
  </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

EDIT

```
var myArray = [

  ["Site1.php", 0],
  ["Site1.php", 0],
];

var X = window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
var i;
for (i = 0; i < myArray .length; i++) {
 if (X == myArray [i][0]) {
   myArray [i][1] = 'active';
 break;
}
}
function Previous() {
  window.location.href = myArray [i-1][0];
}
function Next() {
  window.location.href = myArray [i+1][0];
 }

document.write('<div> <img 
class="header"tyle="width:80%;margin:10%;"src="Files/Logo.png"/> <hr> </div>');

document.write(
'<button class="list" href="#X1" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle"> Home </button>'+
'<div class="show list-unstyled" id="X1">'+
  '<a href="'+myArray [0][0]+'" class="'+myArray [0][1]+'" > 1 </a> '+
  '<a href="'+myArray [1][0]+'" class="'+myArray [1][1]+'" > 2</a> '+
'</div>'
```

);

Comment: No clue what "_doesn't work_" means here, but that's pretty much the way you create a scrollable element. Please show the rendered HTML so that we can reproduce your issue, and explain what "_doesn't work_" means.

Comment: I want the image to be fixed and not be scrolled. The methods ive tried either has got the image fixed in the Website based on browser(Which i dont want) or is scrolling with the menu @Teemu

Comment: Like said, show the full HTML and CSS code for the side-bar, without JS!

Comment: please provide the full code as @Teemu said here

Comment: Im sorry. Look to the edit please @Jimil

Comment: @Teemu Look to the edit please

Comment: Please add the HTML part too, as HTML, not as JS. We don't need all the items in the menu, just so, that it can be scrolled. You can find the rendered HTML from the DevTools' Inspect Element tab.

Comment: just do view page source and copy paste the output here

Comment: Did that. @Jimil

Comment: Pasted the whole page code. Sorry for the delay @Teemu

Comment: can you able to provide below files: 
C-NavigationBar.js   style.css    ace.js

Comment: Have a look @Jimil

Comment: Please remove the JS crap, copy the HTML JS creates from the DevTools instead. The __only__ code we need is HTML and CSS to solve the problem.

Comment: I need the JS code because of a feature of next and previous buttons in my pages. i need arrays to make it simple. @Teemu

Comment: I give up .....

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use Jquery to achieve what you want.

At first, make the position: fixed.

But as you said, I can't take a position fixed, because the menu is collapsable. Now the jquery comes into play.

Wherever you wrote the "collapse" function, add one more line of jquery code to hide your header image.

When the collapsed menu will be shown again, you have to make your header image visible using jquery again.

When all doors get closed, create your own cleverly.

Comment: Image position fixed in the whole window cannot be collapsed and the image fixed in the navigation bar scrolls with the menu. So how is it possible

Comment: Instead of collapse, you can hide the menu with jquery fadeIn() or  fadeOut() function. It will look like a collapse. And your whole menu including image will be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting this errors so before fixing or replicate the issue. I need to resolve the below errors. So if you can please attach the code files would be great.
[image]

Comment: Remove the Lines

Comment: var y = document.getElementById(1);
y.className += " w3-show";
y.previousElementSibling.className += " w3-theme ";

Comment: function myAccFunc(n) {
 var x = document.getElementById(n);
  if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
   x.className += " w3-show";
   x.previousElementSibling.className += " w3-theme ";
  } else {
   x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
   x.previousElementSibling.className =
   x.previousElementSibling.className.replace("w3-theme", "");
 }
}

Comment: its present in the JS part in the HTML File. Remove them